# The keyboard, WiFi and sound card stopped working after installing Windows 7 updates. How to fix this?

Tags: windows-7, audio, drivers, keyboard, windows-update

I have a preinstalled licensed Windows 7 x64 on my Asus laptop. I used to update it via the internet all the time, until at one point this proved to be a bad habit.

I've been offered by Windows Update to update the keyboard driver. I usually told Windows Update not to apply such irrelevant updates, but this time for some reason I've decided to go with it.

After that, the keyboard, WiFi, sound card and probably some other devices stopped working. Looks like only devices which are wired internally in the laptop were affected, because USB devices connected externally work as usual (mouse, for instance). At first I used the screen keyboard but then I've connected an external keyboard.

I am an advanced PC user and I've tried different ways to fix this: rolled back the updates, reinstalled drivers, deleted devices in Device Manager. What else can I do?

Comment: If you have everything backed up I would do a restore. Or possibly run Cmd.exe and run the command `sfc /scannow` to see if something is corrupted in the windows file system and it will try and auto repair it. If it cant I would back everything up and reinstall windows.

Comment: Thank you, @[NetworkKingPin](http://superuser.com/users/515502/networkkingpin), I am already scanning the system, "This process will take some time." `sfc` says. You mean reinstall on top of old Windows or rewrite the Windows?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you mean the roll back option in the Device Manager section when you say "rolled back the updates", which leads me to believe you probably haven't tried a system restore.

That's likely where I'd start. The next place I'd go is the ASUS website to try and find a driver package for that chipset, etc. I'd reinstall all the drivers I could find for the laptop itself.

If that doesn't help, I'm stumped. If I couldn't find experiments on Google, I'd probably just factory restore.

Comment: I think I didn't have system restore enabled, but if I did, I tried that for sure. And I think I tried "Roll Back Driver" button in Device Manager. I should double-check that when I have the access to that system.

I will follow your advice and get the newest drivers for the laptop's hardware. Thank you, @[lol2dubs](http://superuser.com/users/573212/lol2dubs).